# Query is not returning proper value

Tags: mysql, sql

As the part of my [Query question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829856/fetching-data-from-multiple-tables/14832228#14832228) i am trying to write a sql query which is returning null and zero value how to resolve this [please see it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30321/16).

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: It should return valid MESSAGE_ID,SMALL_PIC_PATH,TOTAL_LIKES

Comment: Is this all you want: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30321/22

Comment: :) Yes that I want Thankyou...........

Comment: just remove the single quotes around those values.

Comment: No problem -- I posted the answer below for future help.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your supplied [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30321/16), you need to remove the single quotes around:

```
'user_messages.messageid'
```

to just be:

```
user_messages.messageid
```

The first won't actually match the results.

[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30321/22)