# Combining two queries in one

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching data from multiple table. 
  and tried to [solve this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14829856/required-single-query-to-fetch-data-from-tables)

Finally i got two queries

1) which is fetching relevent data of user message.

2) Fetching all comments and its details.

I want to combine these two queries in one query.

Query 1)

```
SELECT user_messages.messageid,user_messages.message,
user_messages.sentby,user_messages.visibility,

GROUP_CONCAT( post_images.image_id SEPARATOR ';')
AS  `POST_IMG_ID`,


GROUP_CONCAT( post_images.small_pic_path SEPARATOR ';')
AS 'POST_IMG_PATH',

(
  SELECT count(*) FROM likes
  WHERE element_id=user_messages.messageid
  )AS 'TOTAL_LIKES',

smsusers.fname as 'SENTBY_FNAME',
smsusers.lname as 'SENTBY_LNAME',
profile_pic.small_pic_path as 'SENTBY_SMALL_PIC_PATH'

FROM user_messages
      INNER JOIN smsusers ON
        user_messages.SENTBY = smsusers.id
 INNER JOIN profile_pic ON
 user_messages.SENTBY = profile_pic.userid
left outer JOIN post_images ON
user_messages.messageid=post_images.messageid
WHERE user_messages.userid='1'
GROUP BY user_messages.messageid
order by user_messages.adddate
```

Its working link is [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/431ca/1)

Query 2)

```
SELECT comments.comment_id, comments.comment, comments.comment_date,
smsusers.fname ,smsusers.lname,profile_pic.small_pic_path  
FROM comments, smsusers , profile_pic , user_messages 
WHERE user_messages.messageid = 'm1'
AND user_messages.userid = smsusers.id
AND smsusers.id = profile_pic.userid
ORDER BY comment_date
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

Working link is [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/431ca/6)

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself or do you just want others to do your work for you?

Comment: what is your rquired output?

Comment: @Matten I want to combine these two queries in one query.

Comment: @raheelshan All relevent comments should be displayed with message detail in one row

Comment: Hi @tombom I tried but i am not getting how to do this

Comment: Posting what you have tried is always a good idea...

Comment: 'SELECT (<Query_1>),(<Query_2>)' but now working

Answer (score 0):

Use ths query and remove dependant sub query

```
SELECT user_messages.messageid,
       user_messages.message,
       user_messages.sentby,
       user_messages.visibility,
       GROUP_CONCAT(post_images.image_id SEPARATOR ';') AS `POST_IMG_ID`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(post_images.small_pic_path SEPARATOR ';') AS 'POST_IMG_PATH',
       likes.TCount AS 'TOTAL_LIKES',
       smsusers.fname AS 'SENTBY_FNAME',
       smsusers.lname AS 'SENTBY_LNAME',
       profile_pic.small_pic_path AS 'SENTBY_SMALL_PIC_PATH',
       GROUP_CONCAT(comments.comment) AS `Comments`
FROM user_messages
INNER JOIN smsusers ON user_messages.SENTBY = smsusers.id
INNER JOIN profile_pic ON user_messages.SENTBY = profile_pic.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN post_images ON user_messages.messageid = post_images.messageid
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT element_id,
            COUNT(*) AS `TCount`
     FROM likes
     GROUP BY element_id) AS likes ON likes.element_id = user_messages.messageid
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.comment_on = user_messages.messageid
WHERE user_messages.userid = '1'
GROUP BY user_messages.messageid
ORDER BY user_messages.adddate;
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/431ca/11)

Comment: Thanks for reply. Here `POST_IMG_ID` and `POST_IMG_PATH` is repeating multiple times

Comment: I am having one more request can we sort `COMMENTS` based on 'comments.comment_date'

Comment: few more thing i want to fetch 'smsusers.fname' and 'smsusers.lname' of commenter and `profile_pic.small_pic_path` of commenter